# How can I get total amount of payouts for a stripe connect account?

Tags: stripe-payments

Is there a way to get the total amount of payouts for each stripe connect account?

I mean amount for the payouts which still in transit to bank. not the completed ones.

On stripe dashboard, I can confirm that amount for each connect account, but im not sure how I can get that amount on my app by using the API.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to specify the connected account id and external account id when you retrieve connected account's payout list.

```rb
Stripe::Payout.list({destination: external_account_id}, {stripe_account: connected_account_id})
```

When you retrieve specific one payout, like below.

Good:

```
Stripe::Payout.retrieve('po_**********', {stripe_account: 'acct_**********'})
```

Bad:

```rb
Stripe::Payout.retrieve('po_**********')
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're automatic payouts, you need to actually use webhooks and log this data locally so it can be retrieved.  You'd listen for `payout.created`, `payout.paid`, `payout.updated`, `payout.failed`, and `payout.cancelled` events on a Connect Webhook Endpoint.  When you received one, you'd note the amount in your database and access it from your app whenever you needed that information.